# MacBook pro 2012 won't turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, memory

Hello good day I was using my MacBook pro 2012 this morning and it went off I tried turning it on and plug in the charger but it still isn't turning on so I checked on YouTube for solutions to the problem and I got options of using my pressing down my power button and option key including p and r but it's also isn't working so I got a referral from someone to check this website and I believe you have the solution to my problem